# Create Aws Security Group Inbound Rule from another security group in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have multiple *AWS Security Groups* and i want to create an inbound traffic rule in 1 security group from another security group. I can do that from the AWS Console but i want to automate it using java api. How can i do it?

> For simple Rules with Cidr Blocks, I have used **AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest**, But in this i can't find a way to achieve this.

Sample Code:

```
AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest =new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();
authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withFromPort(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getFromPort());
authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withIpProtocol(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getIpProtocols().getName());
authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withToPort(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getToPort());
authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withCidrIp(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getCidrBlock());
authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.setGroupId(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getSecurityGroupId());
amazonEc2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest);
```

Comment: I have two Aws security groups sg-ac9cd2cb and sg-ac9cd2cb and i want to create a security group inbound rule from sg-ac9cd2cb security group to sg-ac9cd2cb. But i am not able to find any api in  aws java sdk.I want to know how can i achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

After some try and error with Aws Apis, I have found the solution with works for me.

We can use the model **IpPermission** instead of setting the rule details with provides the api to add sourceSecurityGroupId.

```
   AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest = new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();

    IpPermission ipPermission = new IpPermission();
    ipPermission.withFromPort(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getFromPort()).withToPort(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getToPort())
        .withIpProtocol(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getIpProtocols().getName());

    if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getCidrBlock())) {
      ipPermission.withIpRanges(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getCidrBlock());
    } else if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getSourceSecurityGroupId())) {
      UserIdGroupPair userIdGroupPairs = new UserIdGroupPair();
      userIdGroupPairs.setGroupId(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getSourceSecurityGroupId());
      ipPermission.withUserIdGroupPairs(userIdGroupPairs);
    } else {
      // TODO throw exception
    }

    authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withIpPermissions(ipPermission);
    authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.setGroupId(securityGroupIngressRequestParam.getSecurityGroupId());

    amazonEc2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest);
```